# Calculation of sound level in dB

Tags: delphi, math, audio

I was never good in math, so I need help how to convert linear value to dB.

First I show you how I calculated the linear value from -24dB.

```
var dB, linearLevel: integer;
begin
dB := -24;
linearLevel := Round( 1/exp( 2.30258509299 * (abs(dB)/20) ) *32767);
end;
```

Where `1/exp( 2.30258509299 * (abs(-24)/20) ) ;` is normalized value.

For conversion to sample value I use `1/exp(...)*32767`

**My problem is here: conversion back**

I was told to use formula `20*log10(linearLevel)`. So I tried to create it but my result is 18 instead 24 (or -24) dB.

```
linearValue := 2067; // the result of the formula above    
db := round( exp( 20*2.30258509299*(linearLevel / 32767) ) );
```

How to calculate the dB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If

```
linearLevel := Round( 1/exp( 2.30258509299 * (abs(dB)/20) ) * 32767);
```

we lose information due to the rounding (in the language of mathematics, the `Round` function is not *injective*). So given a `linearLevel` value, it is impossible to get back the original `dB` value. Therefore, let us consider

```
linearLevel := 1/exp( 2.30258509299 * (abs(dB)/20) ) * 32767;
```

instead. This implies

```
linearLevel / 32767 := 1/exp( 2.30258509299 * (abs(dB)/20) )
```

and

```
32767 / linearLevel := exp( 2.30258509299 * (abs(dB)/20) )
```

and

```
ln(32767 / linearLevel) := 2.30258509299 * (abs(dB)/20)
```

and

```
ln(32767 / linearLevel) / 2.30258509299 := abs(dB)/20
```

and

```
20 * ln(32767 / linearLevel) / 2.30258509299 := abs(dB).
```

Here we again have an issue, since the absolute value function is not injective. If `abs(dB)` is `7`, we cannot possibly tell if `dB` is `7` or `-7`.

But if we assume that `dB` is non-positive, we finally have

```
dB = -20 * ln(32767 / linearLevel) / 2.30258509299.
```

**Simplifications**

Since `2.30258509299` is `ln(10)`, this is

```
dB = -20 * ln(32767 / linearLevel) / ln(10).
```

But `log10(x) = ln(x) / ln(10)`, so we can write

```
dB = -20 * Log10(32767 / linearLevel)
```

where the `Log10` function is found in the `Math` unit.

Also, using the law `a log(b) = log(b^a)` in the case `a = -1`, we can even write

```
dB = 20 * Log10(linearLevel / 32767).
```

Comment: Thank you. The proccess of calculation helped me to understand how it works. I hope I will use this math one day.

Comment: @JohnyBony: Glad I could help. I now see that you have declared `dB` as an integer as well, so you need to add a final `Round` to make it work: `dB = Round(-20...`.

Comment: Just a comment on the number `2.30258509299`. It is an approximate value of `Ln(10)`, which is used to convert the natural logarithm to the 10 based `log`.

Comment: I don't understand logarithms, I haven't have that topic on school. The number I created.

Comment: Indeed: log(X) = ln(x) / ln(10). More generally, logN(X) = ln(x) / ln(N). So in this case, `ln(32767 / linearLevel) / 2.30258509299` can be simplified to `Log10(32767 / linearLevel)`. The `Log10` function is found in the `Math` unit.